# How to view big h5p files

Tags: html

As I understand, h5p cannot be viewed on a local device, e.g. in offline mode (I'm aware of h5p-standalone but it requires setting up a local webserver)
and viewing requires a webserver that supports h5p, e.g. via WordPress plugin.

Assuming that I have a **large** h5p file (e.g. 1G Byte) with many images.
Does this large file needs to be uploaded first to the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run H5P files, you will always have to have some form of runtime environment. That can be (PHP) based like the ones that you already mentioned, but there's also a [node.js port of H5P core](https://github.com/lumieducation/H5P-Nodejs-library) than can be used. That port is also the foundation of the editor/player named [Lumi](https://lumi.education). It uses Electron to edit/play H5P files locally on Windows, MacOS and Linux. So the H5P file will not have to be provided on a webserver to run.

You can also use Lumi (or its functions) to convert H5P files into single HTML files that contain all the code and the stylesheets to run, also media (base64 encoded). Of course, that approach tends to generate large files and you have a lot of redundancy as all dependecies that are required to rum will be inside every single HTML file instead of being loaded as needed - but you can run that file in a browser either from a server or locally without the need for a webserver.